# cgi and asp.net webservice

Tags: asp.net, cgi

How can I create a cgi url for my asp.net webservice?
client want to access the webservice using following url

```
[protocol]://servername/webservice/services.cgi
```

How do I make my asmx webservice avaliable through this url?

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL rewrite module.